# Social media links, crashing containers, and responsive navbar

Tags: html, css

In the "lightblue" background (max-width:800px), my social media links fall behind my images. I've tried position:static and the z-index without any luck.

Next, in the "lightblue" background (max-width:800px), I believe my containers are crashing into each other. I've tried, clear:both; overflow:hidden, and display:flex;

Lastly, I'm trying to make my hamburger, nav bar position vertically, when it is responsive. On desktop, I still want the nav bar to be horizontal.

I am at a loss, please help and thank you so much for helping me on my very first website. :)
Please follow me on Instagram at @glp_princess

The link will take you to my html and css.
https://jsfiddle.net/p4zayr0u/

````
    
    body {
        background:lightblue;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
        margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    }
    
    header {
        position:static;
        height:0px; /*keep?*/
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        background:none;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    .header-inner {
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding-top:1px;
    }```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: In the future I will do that, thank you so much Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your socials become unclickable is that you changed the styling of your header tag at the media query (max-width: 800px). Your social anchors are children of this header tag, and so any changes you make to the header will also effect these anchors. If you want to have position: fixed buttons, I would recommend that you place them as direct children of the body so that they don't get effected by changes you make to other elements.

Current:

```
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="header-inner">  
                <h2 tabindex="1">UX DESIGNER X RACHEL SADATIAN</h2>
                <ul id="social2">
                    <li target="_blank" tabindex="2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mrssadatian/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li target="_blank" tabindex="3"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/glp_princess/?fbclid=IwAR27qjKZXxCRaj4bb6fsdidR5R_9shomiimtR9pCDs5GseWoyfhl1BrkNkQ"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>  
            </div> <!-----end header-inner----->   
            
        ...
            
        </header>
</body>
```

Recommended:

```
<body>
    <ul id="social2">
        <li target="_blank" tabindex="2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mrssadatian/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li target="_blank" tabindex="3"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/glp_princess/?fbclid=IwAR27qjKZXxCRaj4bb6fsdidR5R_9shomiimtR9pCDs5GseWoyfhl1BrkNkQ"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
    <header>
    ...            
    </header>
</body>
```